# what difference between these two binary search codes is not letting code 1 to run properly but code 2 works?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary

code 1

```
class Solution {
  public:
  int helper(int arr[],int n , int k , int l , int r){
      
        // int mid = (l+r)/2;
        int mid = l+(r-l)/2;
        
        if(l>=r ){
            
            return -1;
            
            
        }
        
        if(arr[mid]==k){
            return mid;
            
        }       
        else if(arr[mid]<k){
            l = mid+1;
            
            
        }
        else{
            r = mid;
            
        }
        return helper(arr,n,k,l,r);
  }
  
  
    int binarysearch(int arr[], int n, int k) {
       
        
        return helper(arr,n,k,0,n-1);
        
        
        
    }
```

code 2

```
class Solution {
  public:
    int binarysearch(int arr[], int n, int k) {
        int low=0;
        int high=n-1;
        int mid=low+(high-low)/2;
        
        while(low<=high){
            if(arr[mid]==k){
                return mid;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]<=k){
            low=mid+1;
        }
        else{
            high=mid-1;
        }
        mid=low+(high-low)/2;
    }
    if(k!=arr[mid]){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return mid;
    }
    }
};
```

while submitting for large amount of testcases the code 1 does not work while code 2 works fluently without any errors, i know that recursion is being used in code 1 but that must work right??

i tried changing the "r = mid " to "r = mid -1" but it did'nt worked too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to mention about your code (first version):

Your check that `l>=r` comes before you have checked that maybe `l` and `r` are equal and `arr[l]` is the value you are looking for. When `l` and `r` are equal, you should not bail out with `return false` yet.

Instead, `return false` when `l>r`, because that means the range is *empty*.

Secondly, `r = mid` is not reducing the range enough. By the time execution gets there, it has already been asserted that the searched element is not at index `mid`, so `mid` can be excluded from the range that you pass to the recursive call. So do:

```
r = mid-1;
```

Here is your code with those two corrections:

```
int helper(int arr[],int n , int k , int l , int r){
    if(l>r ){ // <--
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = l+(r-l)/2;
    if(arr[mid]==k){
        return mid;
    }       
    else if(arr[mid]<k){
        l = mid+1;
    }
    else{
        r = mid-1; // <-- 
    }
    return helper(arr,n,k,l,r);
}
```